# Disable dashboard from configuration eclipse file, show dashboard error encountered

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I can't open Spring Tool Suite 3.5.0, I'm getting 'show dashboard' has encountered error, It is possible to disable dashboard from eclipse configuration file ?
I installed jdk 1.8 yesterday, can it be connected with this ?

Answer (score 0):

STS has 2 versions of the dashboard: 1) old - based on SWT form widget 2) new - based on Java FX browser control. I'm guessing that a switch to Java 8 triggered new dashboard to show up instead of the old and you're getting some exception related to Java FX.

You can disable the new dashboard via Preferences. Go to Preferences then Spring -> Dashboard and check "Use Old Dashboard" check-box then apply.

P.S. it'd be nice to see the stack trace of the exception you get when activating the new dashboard. What's your platform? Is it Linux?

Comment: Windows 7, I installed new version 3.6.1 and working.